# How to find a median of odd and even numbers from a list of numbers

Tags: list-manipulation

For a given list, say {94,35,47,29,86,40,46,72,87}, how can I find a list of even and odd numbers.

Here is the output after trying with the suggested solution in the answer.

[image]

After putting the number in list as told by @Nasser, I got the intended output.

I am seeking to solve this problem:

Create an Association that lists the Median of the even and odd numbers respectively under the keys True and False. (Hint: Use GroupBy with EvenQ.)

By applying GroupBy, I could now list the even and odd numbers:

Input:

```
GroupBy[{94,35,47,29,86,40,46,72,87,84,49,82,100,99,7,70,67,63,13,
  91,18,94,94,15,72,39,4,7,31,67,65,37,93,9,4,84,97,60,48,61,91,24,10,
  46,42,28,41,36,62,70,78,38,80,70,63,20,21,7,54,26,17,73,100,56,36,
  54,100,46,0,59,77,80,57,82,63,74,8,47,68,74,54,57,4,90,14,31,88,23,
  30,37,95,44,100,12,23,48,4,14,100,57},EvenQ]
```

Output:

```
True->  {94,86,40,46,72,84,82,100,70,18,94,94,72,4,4,84,60,48,24,10,46,
  42,28,36,62,70,78,38,80,70,20,54,26,100,56,36,54,100,46,0,80,
  82,74,8,68,74,54,4,90,14,88,30,44,100,12,48,4,14,100},
False->  {35,47,29,87,49,99,7,67,63,13,91,15,39,7,31,67,65,37,93,9,97,
  61,91,41,63,21,7,17,73,59,77,57,63,47,57,31,23,37,95,23,57}
```

What is needed is the count. True->54, False->49.

With CountsBy as suggested by @sjoerd-smit, I get the count of even and odd numbers in one command.

```
CountsBy[{94,35,47,29,86,40,46,72,87,84,49,82,100,99,7,70,67,63,13,
  91,18,94,94,15,72,39,4,7,31,67,65,37,93,9,4,84,97,60,48,61,91,24,10,
  46,42,28,41,36,62,70,78,38,80,70,63,20,21,7,54,26,17,73,100,56,36,
  54,100,46,0,59,77,80,57,82,63,74,8,47,68,74,54,57,4,90,14,31,88,23,
  30,37,95,44,100,12,23,48,4,14,100,57},EvenQ]
```

By Median applied individually, I could get the medians of even and odd numbers in the list.

Input:

```
Median[{35,47,29,87,49,99,7,67,63,13,91,15,39,7,31,67,65,37,93,
9,97,61,91,41,63,21,7,17,73,59,77,57,63,47,57,31,23,37,95,23,57}]
```

Output:
49

Similarly, for the list of even numbers.

Might be a way to get the same with one command.

Comment: Please take a look at GatherBy

Comment: @Syed I recommend always using `GroupBy` over `GatherBy`, to be honest. It's just a more powerful function and `GatherBy` can be unpredictable in the ordering of the sublists.

Comment: Dear OP, please start a fresh question for new queries, instead of morphing the question.

Comment: @Syed Did not start a new question as from my previous experience, I was told to remove the first question as I formulated the second question based on input from the first one.

Comment: The problem I have is that I am no longer sure what you are asking. But maybe you want `GroupBy[{94,35,...},EvenQ,Median]`  ( <|True -> 54, False -> 49|> )   or if you want both Counts and Median, maybe `GroupBy[{94,35,...},EvenQ,#]&/@{Length,Median}` ( {<|True -> 59, False -> 41|>, <|True -> 54, False -> 49|>} ). But perhaps you require something else?

Comment: @user1066 Yes, I needed to compute median of even and odd numbers and GroupBy[{94,35,...},EvenQ,Median] worked in one instance.

Answer (score 9):

If you only need the counts, then `CountsBy` is the way to go:

```
CountsBy[Range[100], EvenQ]
```

You can also do it with the 3rd argument of `GroupBy`:

```
GroupBy[Range[100], EvenQ, Length]
```

If you want the results in a list in a particular order (say, even then odd), you can use `Lookup`:

```
Lookup[CountsBy[Range[100], EvenQ], {True, False}, 0]
```

Answer (score 8):

I think this was asked before, but I can't find it now searching.

How about

```
lis = {94, 35, 47, 29, 86, 40, 46, 72, 87}
{Select[lis, EvenQ[#] &], Select[lis, OddQ[#] &]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am sure there are many other ways to do this.

**edit:**

A little simpler version as suggested in comment thanks to kglr is

```
{Select[lis, EvenQ], Select[lis, OddQ]}
```

Comment: you can use simpler `Select[lis, EvenQ]`

Comment: Getting the first few elements in black (attached image with the question). Is it due to some mismatch with global variables?

Comment: @SplendidDigitalSolutions  you need to put the numbers in a list first. a list is `{ ....}` then it will work. You can't just list the number as you did.

Answer (score 3):

Try `Cases`:

```
list={94, 35, 47, 29, 86, 40, 46, 72, 87};
twolists=List[Cases[list, Except[_?EvenQ]], Cases[list, Except[_?OddQ]]]
(*{{35, 47, 29, 87}, {94, 86, 40, 46, 72}}*)
Map[Median, twolists]
(*{41,72}*)
```

With order:

```
List[Sort[Cases[list, Except[_?EvenQ]], Less], Sort[Cases[list, Except[_?OddQ]], Less]]
(*{{29, 35, 47, 87}, {40, 46, 72, 86, 94}}*)
List[Sort[Cases[list, Except[_?EvenQ]], Greater], Sort[Cases[list, Except[_?OddQ]], Greater]]
(*{{87, 47, 35, 29}, {94, 86, 72, 46, 40}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {94, 35, 47, 29, 86, 40, 46, 72, 87};
```

Using `Query`

```
f = Query[Select /@ {EvenQ, OddQ}];

f @ list
```

{{94, 86, 40, 46, 72}, {35, 47, 29, 87}}

```
Median /@ f @ list
```

{72, 41}

```
Length /@ f @ list
```

{5, 4}